# How to insert multiple values into one column separated by semicolumn

Tags: sharepoint-online, column-validation

I have a single line of text field titled 'NOTIFICATION NO' with the following column validation:

```
=OR(LEN([NOTIFICATION NO.])=0,AND(LEN([NOTIFICATION NO.])=9,MID([NOTIFICATION NO.],1,3)="500",ISNUMBER([NOTIFICATION NO.]+0),ISERR(FIND(".",[NOTIFICATION NO.])),ISERR(FIND(",",[NOTIFICATION NO.])),ISERR(FIND("$",[NOTIFICATION NO.])),ISERR(FIND("+",[NOTIFICATION NO.])),ISERR(FIND("-",[NOTIFICATION NO.])),ISERR(FIND(" ",[NOTIFICATION NO.]))))
```

How to insert two or more values separated by semicolon (;) satisfying the above validation condition.

For example: "500123456;500567890;500765456"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can validate this column using calculated formula to meet the requirements. Because, the **length** of the column value is **dynamic**, and none of the followings could be validated dynamically:

```
LEN([NOTIFICATION NO.])=9
MID([NOTIFICATION NO.],1,3)="500"
ISNUMBER([NOTIFICATION NO.]+0)
```

However, if we know the **maximum** number of semicolon-separated (;) values, then it is possible to construct part of formula using **OR** construct.

For example, assuming there are three values like you've mentioned 500123456;500567890;500765456

```
OR(LEN([NOTIFICATION NO.])=9, LEN([NOTIFICATION NO.])=19 , LEN([NOTIFICATION NO.])=29)
```

Also, functions like [REPLACE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/replace-function-3e6288d2-faea-4764-95d4-39dd5e508321) can't be used to replace **all** semicolons to verify if the string contains **only** numbers. Need to repeat this function to a known number, and can't be a dynamic value.

```
REPLACE([NOTIFICATION NO.], FIND(";",[NOTIFICATION NO.]),1, "+")
Output: 500123456+500567890;500765456

The goal is to check ISNUMBER(REPLACE([NOTIFICATION NO.], FIND(";",[NOTIFICATION NO.]),1, "+")+0)
```

It would be better to use some other means like Power Automate or JavaScript to validate the column value.